# How do I access my angular controller when handling a browser 'full screen' event?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, controller

Inside my angular controller (which is a controller that's used for a Google maps directive), I'm adding an eventlistener on the document element like this, so I can detect a change to the browser's 'full screen' mode using the full-screen API:

```
        if (document.addEventListener) {
            document.addEventListener("webkitfullscreenchange", this.fullScreenChangeHandler, false);
            document.addEventListener("mozfullscreenchange", this.fullScreenChangeHandler, false);
            document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", this.fullScreenChangeHandler, false);
            document.addEventListener("MSFullscreenChange", this.fullScreenChangeHandler, false);
        }
```

I'm then handling the event like this in my fullScreenChangeHandler method, which is a method that also sits directly in the controller:

```
    fullScreenChangeHandler(event) {

        var containerScope = angular.element(event.srcElement).scope();
        var map = containerScope.map;
        var mapController = containerScope.$parent.mapsCtrl;
```

So (event.srcElement) = the document node. This method of accessing the controller was working but has somehow broken. In any case, the code feels very smelly, so there must be a better way. I'd appreciate any suggestions of a direction to go in.

Comment: Why do you need access to mapsCtrl?

Comment: I'm implementing custom 'maximise map' and 'restore map' buttons instead of the google maps default, and the 'fullScreenChangeHandler' needs to do map centering and re-drawing when 'esc' is used to exit full screen mode. (I need custom styling as well as custom functionality for the buttons, which is why I'm not using the defaults)

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two other ways to implement your feature.

1) Use $rootScope to fire 'fullscreenchange' and listen event on your controller:

```
// inside fullScreenChangeHandler
// inject $rootScope 
var $body = angular.element(document.body);           
var $rootScope = $bodyF.injector().get('$rootScope');  
$rootScope.broadcast('FULL_SIZE_CHANGED');
```

Listen event normally on MapController with $scope.on('FULL_SIZE_CHANGED',...)

2) Write handler of event inside MapController.

```
//inside MapController
angular.element($window).on('fullscreenchange', fullScreenChangeHandler);

fullScreenChangeHandler(evt){
    //call resize map here
    scope.resizeMap()
    ...
    // you need $scope.$apply to notify angular about the changes because this event outside of angular context:
    $scope.$apply();
}
```

I don't like rootScope and prefer the second one if you have only one listener.

Comment: Code is written in map controller, so why scope is not available

Comment: Thanks Vu, your 2nd suggestion is interesting. A fullscreenchange or equivalent event (it differs between browsers), occurs on the document not the window (and if we're registering the event on an angular object, I would have though that we may not need $scope.$apply, although I'm not completely sure about this). In the actual event handling function (fullScreenChangeHandler), $scope is not available to me in any case - on the map exit the event can be received with the document node as it's source, which means angular won't know which $scope I want to access

Comment: +1 for the 1st suggestion of broadcasting to $rootScope, I think this is probably the way to go although I haven't tested this. To avoid polluting the rootScope though, a specific event of 'mapFullSizeChanged' would be better.

Comment: The important things is that you can call method of MapController directly in your event handler such as scope.resizeMap();

Answer (score 0):

I found that when entering full screen, the source element received by the  fullscreenchange event is a container div within my directive template, so referencing the controller the way I was doing it still works.

The problem was only when closing the map, and in this case the srcElement received by the event is the document node. In the case of exiting, I don't need to access the map.

So, I can check that I'm *entering* full screen mode and get the controller like this:

```
        var containerScope;
        var mapController;

        if (event.srcElement.id) {
            if (event.srcElement.id.indexOf("myMapContainer") != -1) {
                containerScope = angular.element(event.srcElement).scope();
                mapController = containerScope.$parent.mapsCtrl;
            }
        }
```

Then I can do the map centering only if I have access to the controller:

```
        if (mapController) {
           .... center and resize the map
        }
```